# SP2013 Event Receiver action open page library\list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, event-receivers, event-handlers

I want to create **Event Receiver**, but I need an event type that would work when opening the library\list page for example. 
Tell me which event to use? Or is **Event Receiver** not the best solution?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**As a short answer,** There is no Event Receiver type that will trigger when opening a Library/ List Page!!!

**The Event receiver** should be used to trigger a specific action before or after a specific event like Item Added (After), Item Adding (Before),  Item updated (After), Item updating (Before) ...etc

**The alternative solution:**

- Creating a web part that will be hosted in the Library page and add your code (action) to trigger in the `Page Load` event.